# POST <url> net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED trying to login

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have a react app hosted on AWS as two EC2 instances. One for the frontend(ReactJs) and other for the backend (NodeJs with MongoDB as the database). To put the website behind SSL, the frontend instance is wrapped under an application load balancer. All listeners are configured as per AWS documentation along with setting up the security and target groups.
Route 53 has been also setup to allow all connections to the website to be routed to the https link which is working properly.
Problem arises when I open my website and try to login. When this access is being made from the frontend server to the backend url, the above message is displayed in the Chrome console while in Firefox it gives the following error: "Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at . (Reason: CORS request did not succeed)."

Also just to highlight that the issue is only when i've put the website under an SSL certificate. We have also setup two staging servers which do not have any SSL certificate and there's no issue while doing any activity such as login mentioned above.
Please help me identify where i might be going wrong. I had also raised a technical ticket with AWS support but they have only confirmed that all settings related to the Load balancer and instances etc. are correct and have not been able to find the root cause. I have also tested the UFW for the Ubuntu instance which shows invalid so that is also not an issue.

Thanks,
Pranay

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Created a separate application load balancer for the backend instance and then created a cloudfront distribution for this instance. The DNS name of the cloudfront can then be used to access the backend from the frontend.